# окошко при работе скрипта,что бы видеть что прога работает

Tags: python-3.x

можно ли какнить сделать окошко при работе скрипта..ну что бы оно всплывало и закрывалось в процессе работы.так сказать что бы видеть что прога работает?

например на АНК это делается вот так-
Tooltip, программа работает

а вот как сделать наподобие на питоне

Comment: Что значит "закрывалось в процессе работы"? Если вам нужно, чтобы во время работы программы отображалось какое-то окно, то воспользуйтесь библиотекой tkinter.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575708/notification-using-python